# Spark: More than a minute gap between final write and next Stage

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

It's an Iterative algorithm. I'm overwriting the data in HDFS location, with Partition by calendar date & iteration number. I'm trying the write option in 2 ways:-

1st Option:-
Setting the Property `spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode=dynamic` and overwriting by Partition By. This way the write is working as expected and the stages next to write is immediately starting, Please find below screenshot.

[image]

2nd Option:-
Not setting the Property `PartitionOverwrite` and giving the Overwrite path till the Partition column (eg: `hdfs://....../calendar_date={0}/iteration={1}/`), In this way I'm overwriting the `ORC` files after its Physical path. In Option 2, the Overwrite is working as expected but the stage next to it is not starting immediately. Refer below Snapshot. Here you could see gap of more than 1min. Can you please help why the time gap is coming when writing the files till it's physical path.

[image]